# Are aircraft windows UV-ray proof?

Tags: windows

As we know, at higher altitudes the dose of UV rays increases, and planes usually spend a larger time there, then why aren't windows of airplanes made UV proof. A simple coating on the inside might solve the problem.

[Relevant question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/21703/are-suns-uv-rays-more-harmful-on-an-airplane-at-high-altitude)

Comment: are you asking *if* they are, or do you already know the answer and are asking why is it so?

Comment: I would like to know are they UV proof.. Older aircrafts may not be, but maybe some new aircraft might have some coating.. And if they are not, then why don't they address the issue.

Comment: @Firee The top answer to the other question explains it quite clearly: Yes, they are enough UV-proof. I fail to see what you want to achieve.

Comment: @yo: Read the edit on the answer you are referring to. It says it needs some kind of coating. So, do aircraft manufacturers apply any kind of coating?

Comment: Ah ok. Still I don't think it makes sense to ask this question; it would be more sensible to update the answer to the other question.

Comment: Then please consider revising the wording, in your title you ask *if*, but when you say `then why aren't` you are assuming *they aren't*.

Comment: Are you asking about cockpit windows or cabin windows?

Comment: Can't find a specific reference right now but afaik aircraft that fly at higher altitudes have windshields made of laminate safety glass. The same kind as in a car windshield just much thicker. Laminate glass blocks nearly all uv. I don't know about the cockpit side windows, tho. The side windows in a car are usually tempered glass which does not block uv unless it's coated or tinted. Tempered glass is stronger and harder to break but shatters into dangerous shards and upon breaking offers no resistance to penetration. That's why car windshields are required to be laminate

Comment: @Firee, the accepted answer of the question you yourself link clearly explains that the two most common materials for aircraft windows provide UV protection as inherent property of the materials. The last sentence of not being UV-hard refers to the _material itself_ needing specific treatment if it is to be used in application where it will be exposed to sunlight.